# Android: Get layout visibility

Tags: android

I am having scroll view which consists of linear layout. I am adding inflated xml in linear layout. Now on click of that layout i am calling animation for expand and colaps. Everything works fine until your layout is visible. When you tap on last item of the layout,my expanding animation works and layout goes down to screen. I tried with getGlobalVisibleRect but it is not working.

Comment: All i want is - How to get visibility of that layout which is visible on your mobile device.

Comment: Your question is unclear. *"How to get visibility of that layout which is visible on your mobile device"* if it is visible then you already have the "visibility"*...it's visible.

Comment: @codeMagic, are you sure?

Comment: On the contrary, @Blackbelt quite unsure, atm

Comment: @codeMagic- Let me explain you- In scroll view i am adding bunches of layouts. On click of layout i am showing another layout by setting its visibility on. Now what is happening, If 3rd row is in picture which is visible and if i click on 3rd row then my expandable layout goes down to screen.

Comment: you probably mean that the expanded rows goes over the limit of the phone.
i had it with my chat and i solve it with android:stackFromBottom="true"

Comment: @MaorHadad- The expanded view goes down as i have applied animation.It will not see until user scrolls up!!

Comment: ok. so just after animation end set the item to last item.

Answer (score 0):

To get the visibility of a view, you can use `myView.getVisibility()`.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but do you mean:

```
yourView.getVisibility();
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to build an accordian widget.

Refer to this guide
http://android-puremvc-ormlite.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-simple-accordion-panel.html

However, you can achieve what you want by telling scrollview to scroll to the bottom of the page, after your animation is done.